# MVC 4 web api routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

After torturing google for about an hour without getting any viable results I am a little desperate, maybe someone can push me in the right direction.

I set up a basic web api using visual studio 2012 and mvc 4.
After reading various tutorials about routing and some depressing first steps on my own, I am stuck.

My WebApiConfig is still left untouched like this:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now I have a controller called "clients" and a method called "test".
I want to apply this method "test" to a certain "client" so I added

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ClientManagement",
            url: "My/{controller}/{ClientGUID}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Clients", action = "test", ClientGUID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

To my RouteConfig.

Why doesn't it turn out the way I want it to?

[image: MY OWN STUPIDITY]

**EDIT:
I am confused...**
[image]

I can still understand this^

But THIS is beyond my comprehension:

[image]

Comment: do you need "api" in the url string?

Comment: Well, that's the point I try to figure out... I can't find a proper explanation on this :( Maybe I am just retarded ^^'

Comment: Your new route does not start with `api/`, but with `my/`

Comment: Now that I look more closely, your new route has been defined with `MapRoute` but a webApi should use `MapHttpRoute`